# The up arrow in ghcii.sh does not scroll through command history

Tags: windows, haskell, cygwin, ghci

I'm using ghcii.sh and cygwin (windows 10).  The up arrow moves the cursor up one line instead of scrolling through command history.  How do I make it do the latter?

Comment: in some cases you can use <ctrl>-<up> instead (for exmaple in emacs) - maybe it's worth a try

Comment: windows console or mintty ? Haskell is not a cygwin program so the interation with cygwin is not working. [link] (https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/win32-dlls.html#interacting-with-the-terminal)

Comment: @matzeri windows console I believe, as I have not installed mintty afaik

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the poor interaction between mintty and ghci. Unfortunately it is not fixed and probably will never be fixed. Your best chance is to use a console other than mintty.